empty parquet files in autoloader databricks causing a read error
Looking for a solution to ingesting empty parquet files into databricks using autoloader into unity catalog delta tables without causing the stream to fail. we use a batch process that processes parquet files from the landing zone into our ingestion layer delta tables. This is done using control tables per source system that provide the params for where the files will be located in our landing zone as well as where we expect the destination tables to be, looping through each expected table per row.
I've considered not writing the empty parquet files into the landing zone, however, on consideration i'd prefer the workflow to run still and pass over all empty parquet files (no data for the day for that delta loaded table). Currently it gives a read error instead as below:
the below code fails with the following error on trying to ingest an empty parquet because the empty file doesn't contain a schema. We use rescue data columns and the schema is set on initial load.

[STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 123456, runId = 123456] terminated with exception: [FAILED_READ_FILE.NO_HINT] Error while reading file "empty file location".parquet.  SQLSTATE: KD001 SQLSTATE: XXKST

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, current_timestamp, input_file_name
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import time

current_timestamp_col = lit(current_timestamp())

for row in control_df.collect():
    if row['FileType'].upper() == 'PARQUET':
        catalog = catalog
        schema = row['DestSchema']
        table = row['DestTable']
        data_loc = f"/Volumes/{landing_zone}/{schema}/{schema}_vol/{table.lower()}"
        schema_folder = f"{data_container}/{catalog}/{schema}/"
        checkpoint_loc = f"{schema_folder}/_checkpoint/{table}"
        table_uc_path = f"{catalog}.{schema}.{table}"
        
        print(f"loading from: {data_loc} ... destination: {table_uc_path}")

        # Check if the table exists
        if not spark.catalog.tableExists(table_uc_path):
            table_and_checkpoint_prep(table_uc_path, checkpoint_loc)

        df = spark.readStream \
            .format("cloudFiles") \
            .option("inferSchema", "true") \
            .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet") \
            .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_loc) \
            .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue") \
            .option("cloudFiles.rescuedDataColumn", "_rescued_data") \
            .load(data_loc) \
            .withColumn("db_IngestDateTime", current_timestamp_col) \
            .withColumn("db_LZfilePath", input_file_name())

        # Apply the casting function to convert datetimeoffset(7) formatted columns to timestamp
        df = cast_datetimeoffset_columns(df)  # Call the function on the DataFrame

        # Write data to Delta table
        query = df.writeStream \
            .format("delta") \
            .option("mergeSchema", True) \
            .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc) \
            .trigger(availableNow=True) \
            .outputMode("append") \
            .toTable(table_uc_path) \
        
        query.awaitTermination()

print("Autoload Parquet files complete")


Q. How are you creating those empty parquet files? Does it have a schema defined?

That was the issue. We weren't. I've now switched the extraction method to get and assign the schema from source sql to the parquet, mapping it to pyarrow datatypes, before this it was inferred from the dataframe. This solved the problem.
